# getting null in api response Android retrofit

Tags: android, api, rest, null, retrofit2

I was testing the API in the Retrofit for first time, I was putting the code that they were showing but I don't know why my code doesn't work
it just shows that I am receiving the null value;

I was learning to implement the Retrofit library in my android app . so i was following some tutorial and i was following the code but don't know why i am getting this error
i tried to solve the error by changing the url but the response is the same it shows the null.

Please help me out

```
public class Todo {

 private int userId;
    private int id;
    private String todo;
    private boolean completed;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return todo;
    }

    public boolean isCompleted() {
        return completed;
    }
}
```

public interface ApiInterface {

```
@GET("/todo/{id}")
Call<Todo> getTodo(@Path("id") int id);
```

}

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL ="https://dummyjson.com";
    private static Retrofit retrofit= null;

    public static Retrofit getclient(){

        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView hello;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hello= findViewById(R.id.textview);



        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getclient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Todo> call =apiInterface.getTodo(1);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Todo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Todo> call, Response<Todo> response) {


                Log.e("info","onResponse"+response.body());
               

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Todo> call, Throwable t) {

                    Log.e("info","onFailure" + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the plural 's' in todo. Change your path to `@GET("/todos/{id}")`